# How to create a website application inside desktop application

Tags: visual-studio, web, web-applications, desktop-application

I've been wondering, how to create a desktop application, but inside that application is actually a web application. Like example WhatsApp, the desktop version is similar to the web version.

[image: Desktop Version]

[image: Website Version]

Comment: WhatApp looks like the same application in Windows and web but they are not same. Their look and feel is same but they are not the same application. If you want something similar to whatsapp for your application then you need to create your application both as web application and Windows application  supported by same backend.

Comment: it's still possible to embed Chromium in a desktop application with html files or similar solutions, but it goes with some security concerns. There are frameworks that can do both also..

Comment: I see, thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Chetan Ranpariya, those two apps are completely different app that's design to look the same. I can tell that because of the icons. The UWP uses a standard Segoe MDL2 Asset icons and the web app uses another.

Now if you have a web app and you want to create a UWP app from that web app, you can try Hosted Web App. This allows UWP to host your web app within a UWP App. But it only works on ASP.NET web apps.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msgulfcommunity/2015/11/27/bringing-asp-net-website-to-run-as-a-windows-10-app-and-access-camera-using-uwp-api/

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks mate